# AutocompleteActivity with Compose : IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, google-places-autocomplete

We are in the process of migrating our app from XML to compose and migrated a lot of areas in the app.

right now we need to implement Autocomplete from Google Places to one of our Compose screens which helps with a fragment

and whenever we try to invoke it we get the following error

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`

and this is our current code inside our Compose screen.

```
@Composable
fun Autocomplete(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        AndroidViewBinding(
            factory = FragmentPlaceAutocompleteBinding::inflate,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            val autocompleteFragment =
                fragmentManager.findFragmentById(autocompleteFragment.id) as? AutocompleteSupportFragment

            autocompleteFragment?.let {
                // Specify the types of place data to return.
                autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME))

                // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
                autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
                    override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
                        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                        Log.i("TAG", "Place: ${place.name}, ${place.id}")
                    }

                    override fun onError(status: Status) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                        Log.i("TAG", "An error occurred: $status")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So does the theme of your activity use `Theme.MaterialComponents` as its `parent`?

Comment: yes 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"